# How to drawRect in a DataGrid Cell AS3

Tags: datagrid, drawrect

I have programmatically placed my datagrid with fields on the stage and a rectangular shape on the same stage. What I need to do now is to have cells in a column of the datagrid contain the rectangular shape(s), instead of text.

What I am trying to achieve, in short, is have a graph inside the datagrid, eg, Col1 has Name, Col 2 has Score, and Col3 has the rectangle, representing the percentage of the score length-wise. it will be as long or as short as the percentage score. I am able to dynamically vary the length, but I don't know how to place it in the grid's cells.

Your help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was locked into thinking of adding this as a column to the datagrid. I figured out to just add the shape to the datagrid, ie,

```
    datagrid.addChild(myShape);
```

then position it!